# issue in jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Hi I am trying to make a drop down menu. This may be a basic question but I am trying to make it work for the last hour or so but I do not know what is the problem in my code.

The problem is when I hover over the link then it should display drop down links but it does not show it.

Please check my code over here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAPHq/)

**EDIT**

It works in jsfiddle but still it is not working for my here locally

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}
.top-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0; padding: 0;
}
.top-nav li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px; height: 60px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.top-nav li a {
    width: 100px; height: auto;
    display: block; text-align: center;
    background: #cccccc; padding: 27px 0 17px 0;
    text-decoration: none; color: #6b6d6e;
}
.top-nav li a:hover {
    background: lightblue;
    color: #fff;
}
/*---------------------------*/
.top-nav li ul {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}
.wrap {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px #c0c0c0;
    width: 490px; height: 250px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type='text/javscript'>
$(function() {
    $('.top-nav li').hover(function() {
        $('ul',$(this)).show();
    },function() {
        $('ul',$(this)).hide();
    });
});
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class='top-nav'>
        <li><a href='#'>Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class='wrap'>Stuff Here</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class='wrap'>Stuff Here</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it not working in jsfiddle you mean ? There is no prblem with your code, you have to select "jQuery" in the framework panel on the left...

Comment: I added the framework from the left panel now it is working in jsfiddle. Thats what I said in above update that it works in jsfiddle BUT it is not working locally on my computer. I added jquery library there but still not working. I do not know why?

Comment: Difficult for us the know what is not working on your computer. Do you get any error in the browser's javascript console (press F12 to display it) ?

Comment: when I add this line to my code $(function() {alert('hello');}); then when I reload my page it does not even alert anything.

Comment: Are you sure the link to the jquery library is correct `src="jquery.js"`?

Comment: yes it is correct. when I view the source in my browser and click on jquery.js it opens up jquery library.

Comment: There is also one typo in your html: `type='text/javscript'` should be `type='text/javascript'`

Comment: Nice. I've added the solution as an answer if you could accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to load the jquery library on the left nav bar. Check it now http://jsfiddle.net/rsarika/vAPHq/1/

Answer (score 1):

[It works](http://jsfiddle.net/vAPHq/2/).
You should remember to load jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [corrected jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAPHq/4/).

Also, check out that you've selected *jQuery* from the selectbox on the left.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't choose the framework is 'jQuery' :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the piece of code you added:

```
<script type='text/javscript'>  // missing a "a" in "javscript"
```

should be

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```